# GPP Registry Item Level Targeting in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, group-policy

Is there any way to add item level targeting to an existing GPP Registry item via powershell?

I'm in the process of streamlining my build process and I have come up empty for anything item level targeting related.

Edit: To clarify I will be creating active directory groups then appending a registry key to an existing GPP using that group as the item level targeting. This whole process needs to be automated to avoid transcription and logic errors.

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements? I'm not sure why you can't just build the GPO with item level targeting using the standard tools.

Comment: Unfoetunately the built in tools aren't well suited for bulk or frequent changes. I'm looking for a powershell method that I can pass multiple groups to and always get a uniform build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I automated all the steps other than setting up the item level targeting via PowerShell and created a custom MMC snapin that opens straight to the group policy and registry keys in question at the end of my script. 
While not ideal it was the best possible option until MS provides a ready way to script item level targeting.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this interesting:
http://www.sdmsoftware.com/products/group-policy-automation-engine/

A norwegian guy use this module for handling prefernce-printers adding his own cmdlet on top of the SDM-objects:
http://blog.powershell.no/2010/01/18/automate-group-policy-preferences-printer-management-using-windows-powershell-2/